# What is the best way to distinguish beteen "Refresh Post" or a "Real Post Back"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, postback, refresh

What is the best way to distinguish beteen "Refresh Post" or  a "Real Post Back".

This is what I need to attain

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(PostBack && !Refresh)
{
//Do Something
}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking in the context of how to elimit double-submit situations, i.e. where users hit refresh several times after submitting something, in order to reduce the occurrence of doubly- or multiply-saved records?

Comment: Exactly..as the event that created the original post back is fired even during refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a hidden input with a nonce value generated randomly every time the form is loaded (but not on postback), then check if the nonce value got sent twice. If it got sent a second time, it was a refresh.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock...Accepting this answer as this is the right answer to the question (distinguish between "Refresh Post" or a "Real Post Back")  ..  Other two answers talked about a brilliant solution to avoid issues with Post back

Answer (score 3):

I usually do a Response.Redirect to the same page in the postback event.
That way all my `Page.IsPostBack` are real Postbacks and not Refreshes

Answer (score 1):

you could try like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code of Click event
    //..............
    //...............
    // and then add this statement at the end
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); // Can you test and let me know your findings
}
```

Comment: You should take care with Request.RawUrl; that makes you vulnerable to XSS attacks

Comment: +1 Thanks Muhammad.. Issue completely fixed with your solution..  Tried  Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); and its working just fine

Answer (score 1):

Sample working code for the accepted answer

Add this line in designer

```
  <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="Tics1" value="GGG" />
```

Add following lined in the code behind

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    long tics = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Tics1.Value = tics.ToString();
            Session["Tics"] = tics;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Tics"] != null && Request["Tics1"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["Tics"].ToString().Equals((Request["Tics1"].ToString())))
            {
                Response.Write("Postback");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Refresh");
            }
        }
        this.Tics1.Value = tics.ToString();
        Session["Tics"] = tics;        
    }
}
```